# ADFS Dynamic POST Parameters

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, adfs2.0

I am currently working on an SSO integration between my company and a SaaS provider.  We use ADFS 2.0 here.  The SaaS provider is indicating that in order to do deep linking to a particular document I need to pass a URL parameter to them with the document ID on the SAML POST, kind of like:

```
 https://www.saasurl.com/services/SAMLSSO.aspx?_docid=11234
```

The problem is, I cannot find a way to pass this URL parameter on the POST.  Within ADFS I can setup the POST to go to https://www.saasurl.com/services/SAMSLSO.aspx and that works fine, however I can't deep link.  Even if I add the URL Parameter to the query to idpinitiatedlogon.aspx.

After doing some research I think this can be done using RelayState, however the SaaS provider says they don't support RelayState currently.  Am I stuck?  Just missing something?  Or do I need to modify the IDPInitiatedSignOn page to try to stuff this parameter in after auth and before the redirect back to the POST?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as you point out, this is exactly what RelayState in idp initiated sso is normally used for. But if your partner cannot interpret relaystate, you will indeed have to modify IDPInitiatedSignOn to pass the additional query string to the assertion consumer service, which might not be pretty.